# QGraphicItem not correctly drawn when moved around

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

The problem with the following PyQt4 app is that it moves the items too much when I drag them - by double the amount I actually move the mouse pointer, so while I drag the item on the canvas, after "enough movement" in one direction, the mouse pointer ends up outside of the bounding box of the item.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not overriding anything big, as you can see:

The main window:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from grapheditor.ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from grapheditor.customwidgets import GraphViewer
from grapheditor.graphholder import GraphHolder
from grapheditor.graphnode import GraphNode

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.showMaximized()
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.setup)
    def setup(self):
        self.scene = GraphHolder()
        self.ui.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        #self.ui.graphicsView.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1500, 1500)
        self.drawItems()
    def drawItems(self):
        QGraphicsLineItem(0, -10, 0, 1000, None, self.scene)
        QGraphicsLineItem(-10, 0, 1000, 0, None, self.scene)
        item = GraphNode("hello", 0, 0, 30, 40)
        self.scene.addItem(item)

    def getCanvas(self):
        return self.ui.graphicsView
```

The view

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class GraphViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setInteractive(True)
```

The item

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class GraphNode(QGraphicsItem):
    penWidth = 2
    cornerRadius = 10
    def __init__(self, ident, x, y, width, height, parent=None):
        super(GraphNode, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ident = ident
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable|QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.pos().x() - self.penWidth / 2, self.pos().y() - self.penWidth / 2,self.width + self.penWidth, self.height + self.penWidth)

    def paint(self, painter, optiongraphicsitem, widget):
         painter.drawRoundedRect(self.pos().x(), self.pos().y(), self.width, self.height, self.cornerRadius, self.cornerRadius)
         painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
```

The scene is just an empty class for now:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class GraphHolder(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphHolder, self).__init__(parent)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `boundingRect` is incorrect. `boundingRect` should return coordinates in item coordinate system. The scene will add item position to the bounding rect to calculate real item position. Bounding rect must not depend on `self.pos()`. In your case this error leads to double adding and incorrect positioning of the item. Correct implementation:

```
def boundingRect(self):
  return QRectF(-self.penWidth / 2, -self.penWidth / 2, 
                self.width + self.penWidth, self.height + self.penWidth)
```